# POP3 with TLS in Perl - help getting starttls to work?

Tags: perl, ssl, pop3, starttls

I wrote a Perl script that uses POP3 to retrieve mail from a Gmail account.  A while ago, the script became broken, and I suspect it was because Gmail began requiring either SSL or TLS connections when using POP3.

I found [this interesting post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mike_b/2013/05/pop3-with-tls-in-perl.html) on Mike B's blog, which includes this sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SSLGlue::POP3;
use Mozilla::CA;

my $host  = 'pop.aol.com';
my $login = 'myusername@aol.com';
my $pass  = '4Radfsai8fsfd9sdf9sdf';

my $pop3 = Net::POP3->new( $host) || die "Can't connect to $host: $!";
$pop3->starttls(
    SSL_verify_mode => 1,
    SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file(),
) || die "Can't perform starttls: $!";

my $messages = $pop3->login( $login, $pass ) 
  || die "Failed to authenticate login $login on $host: $!";

print "There are $messages messages on $host for $login.\n";
```

Here's a portion of my exact code (some specifics changed for security reasons):

```
use YAML;
use Net::SSLGlue::POP3;
use Mozilla::CA;
use Email::Find;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::Simple;

my $email_finder = Email::Find->new(\&process_email);
my $verbose = 1;
my $email_account = 'my.email@mydomain.net';
my $email_password = 'somepassword';
my $mail_server = "mail.mydomain.net";

print("\nStarted\n") if ($verbose);

$pop = Net::POP3->new($mail_server) || die("Could not log on to server.");

print(" - starttls using " . Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file() . "\n") if ($verbose);

$pop->starttls(
  SSL_verify_mode => 1,
  SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file()
) || die "Can't perform starttls: $!";
```

My issue is that...

```
$pop->starttls(
  SSL_verify_mode => 1,
  SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file()
) || die "Can't perform starttls: $!";
```

... is failing, but I can't tell why.  Any suggestions?

**UPDATE...**

Thank you Steffen.  I've updated my code by adding Debug => 1 and outputting $IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR:

```
$pop = Net::POP3->new($mail_server, Debug => 1) 
    || die("Could not log on to server.");

print(" - starttls using " . Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file() . "\n") if ($verbose);

$pop->starttls(
  SSL_verify_mode => 1,
  SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file()
) || die "Can't perform starttls: $!\n" . $IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR;
```

The error message now is:

```
Net::POP3>>> Net::POP3(2.29)
Net::POP3>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::POP3>>>     Exporter(5.63)
Net::POP3>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::POP3>>>     IO::Socket(1.31)
Net::POP3>>>       IO::Handle(1.28)
Net::POP3=GLOB(0xb41980)<<< +OK Dovecot ready.
 - starttls using /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem
Net::POP3=GLOB(0xb41980)>>> STLS
Net::POP3=GLOB(0xb41980)<<< +OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
Can't perform starttls:
**SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:14090086:SSL     
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate 
verify failed at (my script) line 26.**
```

Is this basically saying, "The Mozilla::CA certificate is not going to work for you."?

Answer (score 1):

There might be several reasons it might fail and it would help if you add Debug => 1 within Net::POP3->new.
I could think of the following reasons:

- The server does not support a STLS command. In this case you wou, would see an error message when running with the Debug flag, you can also could print $pop->message.
- The servers supports STLS, but the SSL handshake fails. In this case you will find more information in the $IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR variable. Typical examples why the handshake might fail

  - the CA of the certificate is unknown (e.g. not in the CA store provided by Mozilla::CA). This is typically the case with servers from private persons, or inside companies or universities. They often don't use public CAs to sign their certificates or even use self-signed certificates
  - no shared cipher can be found. This can be the case with older servers, which like to do MD5. Recent versions of IO::Socket::SSL or OpenSSL disable these insecure ciphers by default.

If this does not help please post the output from Debug and maybe set $IO::Socket::SSL::DEBUG=10 too.

Steffen (author of Net::SSLGlue::POP3, current developer of IO::Socket::SSL)